# JavaScript/HTML: How to position object to right of page?

Tags: javascript, html, position

I have a filter object that I want to position at the right side of the page but I don't know how to move it. What do I need to do in the HTML file to call this and position it at the right side of the page? Do I need to create a function in the .js file for this?

```
  filterItem.append(criterion).append(pattern).append(addFilterButton);
  criterion.before('Filter results by ');
  criterion.after(': ');
  return filterItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will only need to add some CSS rules, you don't need any js for this. There are many way to position an element.

- Use `position` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
- Or you can use `float`

Maybe you should checkout this link http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/